# Back button viewcontroller

Tags: ios, button, viewcontroller, back

I have three viewcontrollers that all have buttons switch to a fourth viewcontroller. On this fourth viewcontroller, I have a back button, which I want to take me back to the viewcontroller that I was originally at.

I can't just use the control drag since that only let's you go to a single controller. How can I programmatically have it send the user to the most recent viewcontroller?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
self.presentViewController(self.presentingViewController!, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

In swift, but I'm sure you can figure out the Obj-C version if necessary. The key is `presentingViewController`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to navigate back to previous view controller,you should implement:

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

If you want to navigate back to root view controller use:

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

Using below line it will navigate to parent view controller

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Using below line it will navigate to main or root view controller

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Using below line it Will navigate to any view controller

```
[self.navigationController popToViewController:viewControllerObject animated:YES];
```